# how to make a small change to the move_base code with a standard ROS installation

Tags: navigation, catkin-make, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I performed the standard installation of ROS KINETIC following this tutorials (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace ; http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu). However I would like to make a small change to the move_base code, (*being more specific I would like to make a small change to the part of the code of the move_base that calls the my own global planner's make_plan method*). Should I download the move_base from github (*could someone provide me with the correct link?*) to my catkin workspace and recompile with catkin_make? If so, how to make ROS use this new version of move_base recompiled instead of the one that came with the standard installation?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354938/how-to-make-a-small-change-to-the-move_base-code-with-a-standard-ros-installation/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2020-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Navigation Stack on GitHub](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation)

ROS will search your [ROS_PACKAGE_PATH](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_PACKAGE_PATH) in order, so packages in your own workspace will be found before the ones in /opt/ros... . Your self-compiled move_base will thus be used automatically instead.

---

Originally posted by [pcoenen](https://answers.ros.org/users/30604/pcoenen/) with karma: 249 on 2020-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1